# Requests with multipart/form-data and no file returns 400

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, multipartform-data

I want to convert the (working) `curl` command to Python:

```
$ curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: text/html; charset=utf-8; profile="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Specs/HTML/1.7.0"' -F wikitext=%27%27%27Mahikari%27%27%27%20is%20a%20%5B%5BJapan%5D%5Dese%20%5B%5Bnew%20religious%20movement%5D%5D -F body_only=true   'https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/transform/wikitext/to/html'
<p id="mwAQ">%27%27%27Mahikari%27%27%27%20is%20a%20%5B%5BJapan%5D%5Dese%20%5B%5Bnew%20religious%20movement%5D%5D</p>
```

Using `Requests`, I replace the file requested at the first position of the tuple I pass to `files` with `None` (apparently an overloaded feature for this API), but I can't still this code to work. It returns a `400`:

```
    import requests
    text = """
    The '''Runyon classification''' of nontuberculous [[mycobacteria]] based on the rate of growth, production of yellow pigment and whether this pigment was 
    produced in the dark or only after exposure to light.

    It was introduced by Ernest Runyon in 1959.
    """
    multipart_data = {
            'wikitext': (None, urllib.parse.quote(text)),
            'body_only': (None, 'true'),
    }
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/transform/wikitext/to/html'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Accept': 'text/html; charset=utf-8; profile="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Specs/HTML/1.7.0"'}
    r = requests.post(url, files=multipart_data,  headers=headers)  # , headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Accept': 'text/html; charset=utf-8; profile="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Specs/HTML/1.7.0"'})
    if r.status_code == 200:
```

**Update**

I tried another solution using `requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder.MultipartEncoder` and it still doesn't work:

```
    from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
    text = """
    The '''Runyon classification''' of nontuberculous [[mycobacteria]] based on the rate of growth, production of yellow pigment and whether this pigment was produced in the dark or only after exposure to light.

It was introduced by Ernest Runyon in 1959.
    """
    from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

    multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
        fields=(
            ('wikitext', urllib.parse.quote(text)),
            ('body_only', 'true'),
        )
    )
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/transform/wikitext/to/html'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Accept': 'text/html; charset=utf-8; profile="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Specs/HTML/1.7.0"'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=multipart_data,  headers=headers)
```

Comment: can you share the value of `text` variable

Comment: Updated with the unit test string.